# Calculating the right count from two tables

Tags: mysql

I've got troubles to select the right number of visible ships and objects. I'll break down the schema to the minimum information to not overload the question. The `ships` table is minimized to show all example data.

First my schema and a [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c13f6b):

Table `ships`: If a ship is in a fleet (`fleetId > 0`) the `locationID` is set to zero as the location is handled by the fleet entry. Those rows are not listed in the example data as they are not useful for the solution (as trex005 has prooven - see his answer).

```
+---------+---------+------------+----------+------------+
| shipid  | userid  | isStealth  | fleetId  | locationId |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+------------+
|      1  |      1  |         0  |       0  |        666 |
|      2  |      1  |         0  |       0  |        666 |
|      3  |      1  |         0  |       0  |        666 |
|      4  |      1  |         0  |       0  |        666 |
|      5  |      1  |         1  |       0  |        666 |
|      6  |      2  |         0  |       0  |        666 |
|      7  |      2  |         0  |       0  |        666 |
|      8  |      3  |         1  |       0  |        666 |
|      9  |      3  |         1  |       0  |        666 |
|     10  |      4  |         0  |       0  |        666 |
+---------+---------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Table `fleets`:

```
+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+------------+
| fleetid  | userid  | numberTotal  | numberVisible  | locationId |
+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+------------+
|       1  |      1  |           5  |             5  |        666 |
|       2  |      1  |           5  |             0  |        666 |
|       3  |      1  |           5  |             3  |        666 |
|       4  |      2  |           2  |             2  |        666 |
|       5  |      3  |          10  |             0  |        666 |
|       6  |      4  |           2  |             0  |        666 |
|       7  |      5  |           2  |             0  |        666 |
+----------+---------+--------------+----------------+------------+
```

**Description**:

Global Note: Even if the test data does'nt shows it: A user can either has ships or fleets or both (at the current location which is not necessary for my problem).

*First*: A **single** view at the ships table: A ship can be stealthable (`isStealth = 1`) or not (`isStealth = 0`). If it is stealthable it should not be included in the `count` if the user as any positiv number of visible ships. But if a user has no visible ship he should be count as 1 (for attacking reasion). For the example data given the total number of visible ships is: `4 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 8*:

- User 1: Has 4 non stealth and 1 stealth, making 4 visible
- User 2: Has 2 non stealth and 0 stealth, making 2 visible
- User 3: Has 0 non stealth and 2 stealth, making 1 visible
- User 4: Has 1 non stealth and 0 stealth, making 1 visible

*Second*: A **single** view at the fleets table: In a fleet it's similar: The `numberVisible` shows the number of visible ships (for other users than the owner) of this fleet while `numberTotal` contains the full number of ships in it. So if a fleet's `numberTotal` is greater than its `numberVisible` this means that there are stealthed ships in it. If the `numberVisible` is zero it means that the whole fleet contains of stealthed ships and is not visible if the user has at least one other **ship or fleet* in orbit, otherwise 1 is added to the counter. For example data given the total number of visible ships of the fleets is: `8 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 13`

- User 1: Has 3 fleets with a total of 15 ships. Of these 8 are visible and 7 are not. Making a count of 8
- User 2: Has 1 fleet with a total of 2 ships. Of these 2 are visible and 0 are not. Making a count of 2
- User 3: Has 1 fleet with a total of 10 ships. Of these 0 are visible and 10 are not. Making a count of 1
- User 4: Has 1 fleet with a total of 2 ships. Of these 0 are visible and 2 are not. Making a count of 1
- User 5: Has 1 fleet with a total of 2 ships. Of these 0 are visible and 2 are not. Making a count of 1

*Third*: The **total** count is the combination of those, again with the rule: If a user has at least one visible ship stealthe are ignored, otherwise he counts as one.
Taken the example data the total count is: `(12) + (4) + (1) + (1) + (1)= 19*

- User 1: Has 4 visible ships and 8 ships visible in fleets, making a total of 12
- User 2: Has 2 visible ships and 2 ships visible in fleets, making a total of 4
- User 3: Has 0 visible ships and 0 visible ships in fleets, making a total of 1
- User 4: Has 1 visible ships and 0 visible ships in fleets, making a total of 1
- User 5: Has 0 visible ships and 0 visible ships in fleets, making a total of 1

**My problem**:
The current legacy code just selects all rows of ships and fleets from *MySQL* and passed them to *PHP* where in a `foreach` loop under the help of several variables and `if/else` statements the numbers are calculated. As with a growing number of rows (as of 100k+) this gets quite slow I want to handle it in a single query as optimum. But this is where I struggle.
I succesfully counted the number of ships and visible ships of a fleet but I'm not able to include the stealth rules into it because of the combination of the `isStealth` attribut and the users.

This is how far I came.

```
select  ((select count(shipid)
          from ships
          where locationId = 666
         )
        + 
         (select sum(numberVisible)
          from fleets
          where locationId = 666
         )
        ) as visibleShips
```

This returns a total of `10 + 10 = 20` which is wrong by description. And as you see the `isStealth` attribut isn't used at all. If I change the query to

```
select  ((select count(shipid)
          from ships
          where isStealth = 0
          and locationId = 666
         )
        + 
         (select sum(numberVisible)
          from fleets
          where locationId = 666
         )
        ) as visibleShips
```

the total count is `7 + 10 = 17` which is also wrong.

I then tried to use the `fleetId` attribute, but resulting in a count of `45`

```
select  (select sum(if(s.fleetId > 0, f.numberVisible, 1))
          from ships s
          left join fleets f on (f.fleetId = s.fleetId)
          where s.isStealth = 0
          and (s.locationId = 666 or f.locationId = 666)
         ) as visibleShips
```

Does anyone has an idea how to include the stealth rules into the query correctly?

Comment: OK, you lost me. Can you reduce your problem to its simplest expression.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry it's the most broken down explanation I got - took me almost two hours to write it so that the problem is clear and example data is given. And trex005 got it - yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a couple of IFs you can calculate visible ships (min 1 if they have any presence) UNION those results with visible fleets, and then SELECT a SUM() for the total

```
SELECT
SUM(visibleTotal) as grandTotal
FROM
(
  SELECT
  userid,
  SUM(visibleShips),
  SUM(visibleFleetShips),
  IF(SUM(visibleShips)+SUM(visibleFleetShips)=0,1,SUM(visibleShips)+SUM(visibleFleetShips)) as visibleTotal
  FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT
      userid,
      IF(totalShips - stealthShips > 0,totalShips - stealthShips,IF(stealthShips > 0,1,0)) as visibleShips,
      0 as visibleFleetShips
      FROM
      (
        SELECT
        userid,
        COUNT(shipid) as totalShips,
        SUM(isStealth) as stealthShips
        FROM ships
        WHERE
        locationId = 666
        GROUP BY userid
      ) as foundShips
    )
    UNION
    (
      SELECT
      userid,
      0 as visibleShips,
      SUM(numberVisible) as visibleFleetShips
      FROM fleets
      WHERE
      locationId = 666
      GROUP BY userid
    )
   ) as userTotals
   GROUP BY userid
) as grandTotals
```

Comment: This gives not the expected result. `SUM(numberVisible) as visibleFleetShips` doesn't return `1` if a user has not ships and only fleets with no visible ships (like user 5). If I change the select of the fleet subquery to `IF(sum(numberVisible) > 0, sum(numberVisible), 1) as visibleFleetShips` the count is too high in total as users with no visible ships and fleets with no visible ships are counted twice. You can reprocude this using the SQLFiddle from above and your statement.

Comment: Slight adjustment, try it now.

Comment: Wow thanks! I was just trying a combination of your first version and the one of Jason by using several `case when then` but yours is much shorter :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following code should work, though it is not tested at all. The syntax might also be slightly off, but the idea is sound.

```
SELECT sum(iif (TEMP.sCount + TEMP2.fCount = 0, 1, TEMP.sCount + TEMP2.fCount))
FROM (SELECT Count(shipID) as sCount, userID
      FROM Ships
      WHERE isStealth = 0
      AND LocationID = 666
      GROUP BY userID) AS TEMP
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT sum(numberVisible) as fCount, userID
      FROM Fleets
      WHERE locationID = 666
      GROUP BY userID) as TEMP2
ON TEMP.userID = TEMP2.userID
```

If there are issues let me know, but the idea is that you are keeping track of the number of ships in and out of fleets for each user, and then seeing if the number visible in both is 0, and if so, counting that as 1. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for giving me new ideas about creating the query. trex005 was faster than me but you answer was helpful too!